# Having an issue with deleting entry from database on my website

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I have echoed my `database table` onto my website and have tick option next to the table where you can `tick` it and `delete` any of the entries from the website, it should delete it from the database. For some reason its not working, I'm a beginner and any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
    <form method="" action="tester.php">
      <?php 

    include 'connect_to_mysql.php';

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking ORDER BY ID ASC");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>DEL</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email ID</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    <th>Collection Address</th>
    <th>Collection Date</th>
    <th>Collection Time</th>
    <th>Make & Model</th>
    <th>Message</th>

    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
          ?>
               <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete_these[]"                                                                                                                         type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
       <?php
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['phonenumber'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['collectionaddress'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['collectiondate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['collectiontime'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['makemodel'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['message'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    ?> <br>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit"                 id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    // Check if delete button active, start this 
    if(isset($_GET['delete']))  {

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    $id = $checkbox[$i];
    print_r($_GET['delete_these']);
    $ids = implode(', ', $_POST['delete_these']);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id IN($ids)";
    echo "<br />SQL: $sql<br />";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    // if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php 
    if($result){

    }
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your form tag by:

```
<form method="post" action="tester.php">
```

then these 3:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))

$id =(int)$_POST['delete_these'][$i];

$sql = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id=$id";
```

at the place of these 3:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete']))

$id = $checkbox[$i];

$sql = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE id IN($ids)";
```

Your  `$id = $checkbox[$i];` works only if `register_globals` directive is on, which is now deprecated (and removed as of PHP 5.4) because of security issues it causes, and if it exists in the version of PHP you are using most hosting services turn it off.

You'll be sending the data through post so you access them through `$_POST`. the `(int)` before the `$_POST` is to cast anything to integer so if the user try to send a string it will become `0`, this will protect you from sql injection.

**SIDE NOTE  you should stop using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Check out [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)**

Comment: @user3554323 updated my answer you have an issue in your query too, you are using it inside the for loop to get 1 checkbox at a time but you are deleting as if you already imploded the string

Answer (score 0):

you have add method in your form tag--

```
<form  method="post" action="tester.php" >
```

and also replace `if(isset($_GET['delete']))` to `if(isset($_POST['delete']))`

Comment: thanks for the help guys, i have made the changes but nothing is getting deleted from the database still :(